# No space concatenating with an empty doc in wl-pprint

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm using [wl-pprint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint) to output a data type with its fields rendered and separated with spaces. Some of the fields can be `Nothing`, so I render them as `empty`. Obviously, I don't want to add an extra space next to an empty string. It was easily achievable with [HughesPJ library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty), as its `<+>` operator has `empty` as unit. In wl-pprint the space in `<+>` is not optional however.

It would be easy to implement myself, given a function to test if `Doc` is empty. My another question is didn't anyone ever need to check for an empty `Doc`? Is it considered to be a drawback of my algorithm design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the "test if `Doc` is empty" part.

`renderCompact` gives you a `SimpleDoc` which you can pattern-match for `SEmpty`.

It seems sufficiently lazy, e.g.

```
case ( renderCompact $ vcat $ repeat $ text "foobar" ) of 
   SEmpty -> True ; _ -> False
```

Comment: That's smart. I'd like to have a more explicit and clear way to do it and not to rely on laziness, however it should work, I think.